# The Elastic Beanstalk command Request Logs doesn't work on my custom Windows AMI

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I created a custom AMI for use in an Elastic Beanstalk environment as described [here](http://biztech.sheprador.com/?p=153). It all works, except for requesting log files from the instances. When using the Console, when I click "Request Logs|Last 100 lines", it show a Loading spinner for a rather long time and then leaves the list of downloadable logs empty.

I already tried enabling all Logging related checkboxes in the EC2Config dialog before creating the AMI, but this did not help.